# Ubuntu 16.04 Error Processing archive mysql-common

Tags: apt, mysql

I've a problem when I'm tried to run apt-get update, error appears as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient20 : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

After that I run apt-get -f install as suggestion, but Other error appears as follow:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
90 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/264 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.680 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 235067 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04) over (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys', which is also in package mariadb-server-core-10.0 10.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Should I remove mysql completely to fix this? Please advise.

Comment: Sounds like `maria-db-server-core` is using some files from mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mbahlol i was able to fix the issue by the following command :

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
```

When you first do you

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

mysql-common explain that it can t find a previous mysql configuration file, so i created it and it seems that everything works fine now, hope it will be the same for you